not all server names are being properly handled by nginx
The following configuration for an nginx sites-enabled file is directing traffic to the application in a limited manner.
The first 8 server_names were rendering (and still are rendering) as expected directing traffic to the application.
When an expansion of the certificate was called, inserting the additional domains to the server_name statement was omitted and the default file was amended with the cert.
The default file was edited and a certificate re-issuance requested.  However, the status has remained the same - the first eight render the others not, as the certificate was created but not installed in the file.  Now, nginx -t indicates a conflicting server name [...]  on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored for each of the domains listed under server_name
What should be done to rectify this situation?
server {

  server_name sandbox.delfy.club sforst.delfy.club sspillert.delfy.club ssaloon.delfy.club sspillerr.delfy.club samicocard.delfy.club sterlicher.delfy.club scspiero.delfy.club sbazar.delfy.club sbin.delfy.club sgaia.delfy.club sgela.delfy.club sguatto.delfy.club ssignor.delfy.club skukanja.delfy.club slanza.delfy.club sorso.delfy.club sweb.delfy.club;

  root /home/deploy/fidelity/current/public;

  passenger_enabled on;
  passenger_app_env development;

  location /cable {
    passenger_app_group_name fidelity_websocket;
    passenger_force_max_concurrent_requests_per_process 0;
  }

  # Allow uploads up to 100MB in size
  client_max_body_size 100m;

  location ~ ^/(assets|packs) {
    expires max;
    gzip_static on;
  }
    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/sandbox.delfy.club-0001/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/sandbox.delfy.club-0001/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
  server_name sandbox.delfy.club sforst.delfy.club sspillert.delfy.club ssaloon.delfy.club sspillerr.delfy.club samicocard.delfy.club sterlicher.delfy.club scspiero.delfy.club sbazar.delfy.club sbin.delfy.club sgaia.delfy.club sgela.delfy.club sguatto.delfy.club ssignor.delfy.club skukanja.delfy.club slanza.delfy.club sorso.delfy.club sweb.delfy.club;
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
}


Have you tried adding all domains to both the server blocks so all are defined on the port 443 and port 80 server blocks to see what happens? This would mean the cert for SSL would need to handle all the domains too like SAN entries (or wildcard).

My bad. typo.  both server_name statements are identical in the file.  Still, that would not explain why all domains are generating a conflicting name, IMHO...

This is kind of a mess. Is there a REALLY good reason you don't get a wildcard cert for *.delfy.club ?

if the server_name instruction has only one domain, it still hits the conflicting name error

Don't use the server_name directive in the server listening on port 80. And as long as the DNS resolutions point to your webserver, they should be handled by that server block and redirect the browser to https. That should solve your issue.

Use nginx -T (uppercase T) to view the entire configuration across all included files and identify where the duplicate server names are coming from. Is the server block being read twice, or is there a backup file left behind by your editor?
